# yarn --version returns 1.15.2 but 1.19.1 in package.json

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I just re-install `yarn` on React Native 0.61.2 app to the latest 1.19.1.

```
 npm install yarn
```

Then reinstall modules with `yarn install`,

```
 yarn install
```

then  `yarn --version` still returns again 1.15.2 while it is 1.19.1 in package.json. Here is the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.11.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "socket.io-client": "2.3.0",
    "yarn": "^1.19.1"
  },
```

What is wrong with the `yarn` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have yarn package by globally, this mays return global yarn version. if you want be sure of yarn version of your project, you need to check **"node_modules"** file of your project. Last but not least, you should delete **"package-lock.json"** and **"yarn.lock"** files before you install new minor version of your package.